# Azure website losing secure SSL/Https after log in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-identity

It's not necessarily "going away", but when my application loads, the https layer is applied correctly.
[Initial Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujRwa.png)

Then you log in using MVC Identity 2.0 and the SSL lock changes to an information warning.

[After Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PggHO.png)

I have several published applications to Azure using SSL. They all use the same login process, but this is the only site that loses SSL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what does the information warning say if you click it?

Comment: The site isn't using a private connection. Someone might be able to see or change the information you send or get through this site. 

On some sites, you can visit a more secure version of the page:

Select the address bar.
Delete http://, and enter https:// instead.
If that doesn't work, contact the site owner to ask that they secure the site and your data with HTTPS.

Comment: But the certicate is displayed as valid

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at your screenshots for before and after login and can see exactly what you mean about the browser showing the green 'Secure' message before login and showing an information warning instead after login.

In these cases, the problem tends not to be a problem with the SSL certificate itself - if your certificate wasn't valid you'd be more likely to see a red 'Not Secure' warning instead - something like this:

[image: Not Secure]

The problem is far more likely to be an issue with **mixed content**. This means that while the HTML content for the page itself is loading securely over HTTPS, there may be other resources that the page references (such as CSS files, JavaSript files, images etc) that are loading over plain HTTP.

I'd recommend opening the developer tools in your browser (in Chrome for Windows, for example, you can open this by pressing F12). You'll likely see a yellow warning icon which you can click on to get further information. If you have mixed content issues, it'll show you which resources are causing the problem.

[image: Developer Tools Warning]

The image below shows an example of a mixed content warning:

[image: Mixed Content Warning]

The important thing about using an SSL certificate and loading pages over HTTPS, is that your page is only really secure if **all** the assets the page needs to run are loaded securely over HTTPS too. For example, you could load a page loads over HTTPS, but include a reference to a JavaScript file over plain HTTP, e.g.:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/myjavascript.js"></script>
```

In this case, an attacker could potentially manipulate the JavaScript file content before it gets to the user's browser, and insert malicious code into it, which could then compromise the entire page. To fix this, you simply need to change the code to:

```
<script src="https://www.example.com/myjavascript.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps to point you in the right direction to find the source of the problem.

Also on the subject of security and SSL/TLS, because you're implementing a login system, you'll also want to make sure that any auth cookies your site uses are:

- set to `Secure`. This will ensure that the cookies' content will only be transmitted securely over HTTPS.
- set to `HttpOnly`. This will ensure that JavaScript code on your pages have no access to these cookies.

You can verify which of your cookies are set to `Secure` and `HttpOnly` using your browser's developer tools.